# How to find out and update the C++XX version used in python setuptools.command.build_ext

Tags: python, c++, c++11, setuptools

I'm trying to install a third-party python package using pip (which includes bindings of C++ functions). It has worked on my personal computers (running Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.10).

But I get an error when trying to install in on a cluster server, which appears to be due to the C++ compiler. I would like to understand where the error is coming from (and if it can be fixed without `sudo`).

Sorry if the following isn't presented well, I am not entirely familiar with using `setuptools`, or with C++ and using C++ bindings in python. I tried my best to present the information I have that I think is relevant.

Looking into the package's `setup.py` module (the package is `george`), I find the following relevant lines of code:

```
import tempfile
import setuptools
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

# ... code ...

# Defines an object which inherits _build_ext (i.e build_ext)
class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        # ... several lines of code and defined methods...

        # At one point, it checks if self.compiler has a 'flag': "-std=c++11"
        # This is done in a bit of a convoluted way, but I tried to extract
        # the crucial parts of the code here:

        compiler = self.compiler         # I believe this is a property of setuptools.command.build_ext.build_ext
        flagname = "-std=c++11"

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", suffix=".cpp") as f:
            f.write("int main (int argc, char **argv) { return 0; }")
            try:
                compiler.compile([f.name], extra_postargs=[flagname])
            except setuptools.distutils.errors.CompileError:
                raise RuntimeError(...)

            # ... Otherwise continues on...
```

So I am getting the RuntimeError near the end. If it also helps, the error message is:

```
RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!
```

So some sort of C++ compiler doesn't have `C++11` support. I am trying to figure this out, so I have several questions:

1. How do I find out the compiler this is talking about, i.e the one in `setuptools.command.build_ext.build_ext`? Is this anything to do with my `g++`? And how do I ensure the compiler it's referring to has "C++11" support?
2. Is there some way to fix this, or to upgrade something? Unfortunately, this is on a cluster server, as a result I don't have sudo permissions. But I checked and `gcc` and `g++` appear to be installed, with version `4.4.7 20120313 (red Hat 4.4.7-18)`

Comment: That is an ancient version of GCC - current is version 8. You need to get at least 5 installed.

Comment: Ah that's worrying for me. I assume updating gcc would generally need sudo. Also, does `setuptools` use my local `gcc` by default or can that be changed?

Comment: C++11 refers to a version of the C++ standard. The compiler you have, g++ 4.4, does not support C++11, however it has C++0x which is C++11 name before the standard was finished.

Comment: @f4 But that doesn't mean it actually supports anything but a subset of C++11. The OP really needs a more modern version of GCC. Also, there will be ABI changes to consider.

Comment: yes, but maybe 0x could suffice, it's actually called C++11 from version 4.7 but it doesn't mean support is complete: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html

Comment: Would it be worth trying to "trick" this part of setup to continue and install the package anyway, hoping that it all works out at runtime? Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: No, that likely will not work.  You could build a newer version of gcc and install it somewhere you have access to.  I think setuptools will use the C++ compiler given by the `CXX` environment variable.

Comment: it could work but you're likely to run into problems... g++ 4.4 does have quite a bit of missing stuff: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html alternativelly you could install a newer gcc, search so/google there is some help with this

Comment: @MilesBudnek Right that sounds like a good lead, thanks I'll give it a go. In any case, are there some resources you could point me to for doing that? I haven't done any of this before.

Comment: GCC's [installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) are probably the best place to start.